# error while pushing to heroku from main branch

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to push to a brand new Heroku page and I get this message

```
To https://git.heroku.com/sample.git
     ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sample.git'
```

I'm doing git push heroku main, I remember there was some trouble with this, can anyone help me to find the right command?

full error message:

```
-> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 685.2M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 654c4ea20326327d2e8f610ceb00605f954e400c
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 654c4ea20326327d2e8f610ceb00605f954e400c
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to sample.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/sample.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sample.git'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+The+same+version+of+this+code+has+already+been+built

Comment: You have *two* errors here: the "slug size exceeded" one, for which Heroku has printed some advice, and the "already deployed" one, for which Heroku has printed some advice. Read the advice and follow it. This is not a Git issue.